# MySQL and PHP increase performance

Tags: php, mysql

I was given this code to work with, and I'm looking to speed this code up. This little bit is killing load time for this page, and hogging server resources. Any ideas?

```
$Actv = 0;
$ActvCount = -1;
$ActvUpgrade = 0;
$ActvRenewal = 0;
$ActvVehicleAdds = 0;
$renewalCount = 0;
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT OperatorID, Username 
FROM tblOperators 
WHERE OperatorLocale='USA' AND 
OperatorStatus='ACTIVE'");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
 $operID = $row2['OperatorID'];
 $operName = $row2['Username'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT PaymentReason, 
 PaymentMethod, 
 ChargeAmount, 
 UserID, 
 PaymentDate, 
 PackageID 
 FROM tblUserPayments 
 WHERE OperatorID = '$operID' AND 
 PaymentStatus='OK' AND 
 PaymentDate LIKE '$currentDate%'"
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($row['PaymentReason'] == 'ACTIVATION') {
    ++$ActvCount;
    if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK') {
        $ActvUpgrade += $row['ChargeAmount'];
    }
}
elseif($row['PaymentReason'] == 'UPGRADE') {
    $userid = $row['UserID'];
    $paymentdate = $row['PaymentDate'];
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT DueDate FROM tblRenewalInvoices WHERE UserID='$userid' AND ('$paymentdate' >= DATE_SUB(DueDate, INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND '$paymentdate' < DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 15 DAY)) AND ParentInvoiceID IS NULL ORDER BY InvoiceNum DESC LIMIT 1");
    if($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $packageid = $row['PackageID'];
        $pack = mysql_query("SELECT ExpirationDate, Package FROM tblUserPackages WHERE PackageID='$packageid';");
        if($pack1 = mysql_fetch_array($pack)) {
            $expDate = $pack1['ExpirationDate'];
            $dueDate = $row1['DueDate'];
            $days = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT TO_DAYS('$expDate')-TO_DAYS('$dueDate');"));
            $months = (int)( ((int)$days + 14) / 30.4);
            $years = (int) ( ((int)$days + 182) / 365);
            $Intervals = 0;
            if($years > 0){
                $Intervals = $years;
            } if(($pack1['Package'] or 'GPS-SVL') or ($pack1['Package'] == 'GPS-1') or ($pack1['Package'] == 'GPS-1PLUS')) {
                if($Intervals > 1){
                    if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK') {
                        ++$renewalCount;
                        $Actv += $row['ChargeAmount'];
                    }
                } else{
                    if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK') {
                        ++$renewalCount;
                        $ActvRenewal += $row['ChargeAmount'];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ++$renewalCount;
                $Actv += $row['ChargeAmount'];
            }
        } else {
        }
    }   else {
        if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK')
            $ActvUpgrade += $row['ChargeAmount'];
    }
} elseif($row['PaymentReason'] == 'ADDVEHICLE') {
    if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK')
        $ActvVehicleAdds += $row['ChargeAmount'];
}
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Charged, RenewYears, RenewTotal FROM tblRenewalCalls WHERE OperatorID = '$operID' AND PayStatus='OK' AND DateSubmitted LIKE '$currentDate%'");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($row['Charged']) {
    if ((int)$row['RenewYears'] > 1) {
        ++$renewalCount;
        $Actv += $row['RenewTotal'];
    } else {
        ++$renewalCount;
        $ActvRenewal += $row['RenewTotal'];
    }
}
}
}

if($ActvCount != 0) {
 $PerActv = ($ActvUpgrade+$ActvVehicleAdds) / $ActvCount;
} else {
 $PerActv = 0;
}

$total = $Actv+$ActvRenewal+$ActvUpgrade+$ActvVehicleAdds;

# Fix to show proper renewal dollars
$ActvRenewal = $total - ($ActvVehicleAdds + $ActvUpgrade);

$AvgRenewal = ($ActvRenewal) / $renewalCount;

$upgradeEarned = $ActvUpgrade;
$renewalEarned = $ActvRenewal;
```

Here is my code so far, but I don't know where to go from here, as I'm not that experienced in MySQL yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT o.OperatorID AS OperatorID, o.Username AS Username, 
    up.PaymentReason AS PaymentReason, up.PaymentMethod AS PaymentMethod,
    up.ChargeAmount AS ChargeAmount, up.UserID AS UserID, 
    up.PaymentDate AS PaymentDate, up.PackageID AS PackageID,
    rc.Charged AS Charged, rc.RenewYears AS RenewYears,
    rc.RenewTotal AS RenewTotal, p.ExpirationDate AS ExpirationDate, 
    p.Package AS Package
FROM tblOperators o
    JOIN tblUserPayments up ON up.OperatorID = o.OperatorID
    JOIN tblRenewalCalls rc ON o.OperatorID = rc.OperatorID
    JOIN tblRenewalInvoices i ON up.UserID = i.UserID
    JOIN tblUserPackages p ON up.PackageID = p.PackageID
WHERE (o.OperatorLocale='USA' AND o.OperatorStatus='ACTIVE') AND
    (up.PaymentStatus = 'OK' AND up.PaymentDate LIKE '$currentDate%') AND
    (rc.PayStatus = 'OK' AND rc.DateSubmitted LIKE '$currentDate%')
```

Comment: Rather than trying to join it all into one big query for now work in stages.  So join your first query and second query and remove that while loop.  Check performance of page.  Then merge your new joined query with query 3 remove out the next loop and so forth testing along the way it'll a) make things easier to work out/keep straight in your head and b) show you perhaps you don't need to join the whole lot only part of it to get it up to speed.

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` before that query and run it in phpMyAdmin (or some other MySQL console).  That should tell you what indexes (if any) that query is using.  Chances are it's the query here that's slow.  (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`)

Answer (score 0):

A quick play and I think you can merge the 1st and 2nd selects fairly easily. Same for the 3rd and 4th queries, in which case the 5th (that just gets a difference between a couple of dates from those queries) can easily be merged in.

Not tested but something like this:-

```
<?php 

$Actv = 0;
$ActvCount = -1;
$ActvUpgrade = 0;
$ActvRenewal = 0;
$ActvVehicleAdds = 0;
$renewalCount = 0;

$prev_operID = null;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT tblOperators.OperatorID,
                                tblUserPayments.PaymentReason, 
                                tblUserPayments.PaymentMethod, 
                                tblUserPayments.ChargeAmount, 
                                tblUserPayments.UserID, 
                                tblUserPayments.PaymentDate, 
                                tblUserPayments.PackageID 
                        FROM tblOperators
                        INNER JOIN tblUserPayments 
                        ON  tblOperators.OperatorID = tblUserPayments.OperatorID  
                        WHERE tblOperators.OperatorLocale='USA' 
                        AND tblOperators.OperatorStatus='ACTIVE'
                        AND tblUserPayments.PaymentStatus='OK' 
                        AND tblUserPayments.PaymentDate LIKE '$currentDate%'"
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    if($row['PaymentReason'] == 'ACTIVATION') 
    {
        ++$ActvCount;
        if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK') 
        {
            $ActvUpgrade += $row['ChargeAmount'];
        }
    }
    elseif($row['PaymentReason'] == 'UPGRADE') 
    {
        $userid = $row['UserID'];
        $paymentdate = $row['PaymentDate'];
        $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT tblRenewalInvoices.DueDate 
                                        tblUserPackages.ExpirationDate, 
                                        tblUserPackages.Package,
                                        tblUserPackages.PackageID,
                                        TO_DAYS(IFNULL(tblUserPackages.ExpirationDate, 0)) - TO_DAYS(tblRenewalInvoices.DueDate) AS days_diff
                                FROM tblRenewalInvoices 
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblUserPackages
                                ON tblUserPackages.PackageID  = tblRenewalInvoices.PackageID
                                WHERE UserID='$userid' 
                                AND ('$paymentdate' >= DATE_SUB(DueDate, INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
                                AND '$paymentdate' < DATE_ADD(DueDate, INTERVAL 15 DAY)) 
                                AND ParentInvoiceID IS NULL 
                                ORDER BY InvoiceNum DESC LIMIT 1");
        if($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
        {
            if($row1['PackageID'] != '') 
            {
                $expDate = $row1['ExpirationDate'];
                $dueDate = $row1['DueDate'];
                $days = $row1['days_diff'];
                $months = (int)( ((int)$days + 14) / 30.4);
                $years = (int) ( ((int)$days + 182) / 365);
                $Intervals = 0;
                if($years > 0)
                {
                    $Intervals = $years;
                } 
                if(($row1['Package'] or 'GPS-SVL') or ($row1['Package'] == 'GPS-1') or ($row1['Package'] == 'GPS-1PLUS')) 
                {
                    if($Intervals > 1)
                    {
                        if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK') 
                        {
                            ++$renewalCount;
                            $Actv += $row['ChargeAmount'];
                        }
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK') 
                        {
                            ++$renewalCount;
                            $ActvRenewal += $row['ChargeAmount'];
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    ++$renewalCount;
                    $Actv += $row['ChargeAmount'];
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
            }
        }   
        else 
        {
            if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK')
            $ActvUpgrade += $row['ChargeAmount'];
        }
    } 
    elseif($row['PaymentReason'] == 'ADDVEHICLE') 
    {
        if($row['PaymentMethod'] == 'CREDITCARD' || $row['PaymentMethod'] == 'PAPERCHECK')
        $ActvVehicleAdds += $row['ChargeAmount'];
    }
    if ($prev_operID != $row['OperatorID'])
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT Charged, RenewYears, RenewTotal FROM tblRenewalCalls WHERE OperatorID = '".$row['OperatorID']."' AND PayStatus='OK' AND DateSubmitted LIKE '$currentDate%'");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            if($row['Charged']) 
            {
                if ((int)$row['RenewYears'] > 1) 
                {
                    ++$renewalCount;
                    $Actv += $row['RenewTotal'];
                } 
                else 
                {
                    ++$renewalCount;
                    $ActvRenewal += $row['RenewTotal'];
                }
            }
        }
        $prev_operID = $row['OperatorID'];
    }
}

if($ActvCount != 0) 
{
    $PerActv = ($ActvUpgrade+$ActvVehicleAdds) / $ActvCount;
} 
else 
{
    $PerActv = 0;
}

$total = $Actv+$ActvRenewal+$ActvUpgrade+$ActvVehicleAdds;

# Fix to show proper renewal dollars
$ActvRenewal = $total - ($ActvVehicleAdds + $ActvUpgrade);

$AvgRenewal = ($ActvRenewal) / $renewalCount;

$upgradeEarned = $ActvUpgrade;
$renewalEarned = $ActvRenewal;
```

the last select is a little more strange. Might be able to merge it in with a little more thought. It might also be possible to just do it once using up a built up IN clause of operator ids, in which case you should be able to get the summed up values directly in the SQL rather than adding them up in php.